# Getting Managed package to use latest Exchange Rates

Tags: managed-package, zuora

I am trying to get a managed package (Zuora) to use the latest Exchange rate in my org, we use dated exchange rates and we use 3 rates and need it to at least use the latest exchange rate. Is it possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately Salesforce only supports dated exchange rates natively within the context of [opportunities](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=administration_about_advanced_currency_management.htm). I don't know anything about Zuora but my guess is that their solution is built on custom objects which are not supported by dated exchange rates.  There is an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpUrAAK) that addresses this issue but it doesn't look like it will be supported anytime soon.

I had a similar issue on a project I worked on recently.  Fortunately for us, this was a custom application we built and I was able to access the dated exchange rates via Apex which we then applied to our custom object records.  Since you are dealing with a managed package, you would have to work with the vendor to see if they can enhance their application to support multi-currency with dated exchange rates (or somehow extend their application and do this yourself).  [Here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13392/how-to-use-advanced-currency-management-acm-in-custom-objects/16236#16236) is a post from a developer at FinancialForce that discusses this issue and how they had to essentially build their own currency conversion system from the ground up to support advanced currency management.