# Error [System.HttpResponse[Status=Unauthorized, StatusCode=401]] when updating currency table

Tags: api, scheduled-apex

Code:

```
global class CurrencyExchangeRateScheduler implements Schedulable
{
    public String sessionId;

    public CurrencyExchangeRateScheduler()
    {
        String username = 'username';
        String password = 'password+security_token';

        partnerSoapSforceCom.Soap sp = new partnerSoapSforceCom.Soap();

        partnerSoapSforceCom.LoginResult loginResult = sp.login(username, password);

        sessionId = loginResult.sessionId;

    }

    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx)
    {
        UpdateDailyCurrencyExchangeRate(sessionId);
    }

    @Future(callout=true)
    public static void UpdateDailyCurrencyExchangeRate(string sessionId)
    {
        system.debug('sessionId: '+sessionId);
        ...

        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + sessionId);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setMethod('POST');

        for(CurrencyType currType : currencies)
        {
            if(!currType.IsCorporate)
            {
                req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v28.0/sobjects/CurrencyType/'+currType.id+'?_HttpMethod=PATCH');

                req.setBody('{ "ConversionRate" : 2.5 }');

                HttpResponse response = h.send(req);    

                system.debug('response: '+response);
             }
        }
    }
}
```

> Debug: response: System.HttpResponse[Status=Unauthorized,
>   StatusCode=401]

I also tried with the Authorization header as `Bearer` + sessionId.

But again the same issue.

The code works perfectly fine when I am loggedin to the org. But when the class is scheduled and I am not loggedin, the response status is 'Unauthorized' and the currency table is not updated.

How can I get the session Id when User is not loggedin?

Comment: Swati -- you state elsewhere on this page that you tried within your @future  to login and get a new sessionId. Please update your post to show how you did that and what results you get as that approach should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you schedule a class its execution is postpone to the future time.

While actually executing it the session id you passed may not be valid, so you have 2 options.

1) Extended the session validity by -> Setup->Security Controls-> Session settings and set session time out to MAX (12 hours)
(Hopefully your code will be extended in next 12 hours)

2) Modify your UpdateDailyCurrencyExchangeRate method to include login call.

```
@Future(callout=true)
public static void UpdateDailyCurrencyExchangeRate()
{

    String username = 'username';
    String password = 'password+security_token';

    partnerSoapSforceCom.Soap sp = new partnerSoapSforceCom.Soap();

    partnerSoapSforceCom.LoginResult loginResult = sp.login(username, password);

    sessionId = loginResult.sessionId;

    system.debug('sessionId: '+sessionId);


    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + sessionId);
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setMethod('POST');

    for(CurrencyType currType : currencies)
    {
        if(!currType.IsCorporate)
        {
            req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v28.0/sobjects/CurrencyType/'+currType.id+'?_HttpMethod=PATCH');

            req.setBody('{ "ConversionRate" : 2.5 }');

            HttpResponse response = h.send(req);    

            system.debug('response: '+response);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had already implemented the option 1 but it didn't work.

Comment: I get a compilation error: Invalid type: partnerSoapSforceCom.Soap

Answer (score 1):

The below link helps you to fix your issue. i too had previously same issue so i started a thread and got the solution. Check it once.
     [SessionID problem in Schedule Batch class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22704/sessionid-problem-in-schedule-batch-class)

Comment: This didnt work for me. I tried this solution also.

Comment: What error you are getting when you try this because it works perfectly for me.

Comment: I have the same issue with this approach.  The code works perfectly fine when I am loggedin to the org. But when the class is scheduled and I am not loggedin, the response status is 'Unauthorized' and the currency table is not updated.

Answer (score -1):

If authentication error occurs as 401-Unauthorized Header, even after using the correct http headers, try replacing the org instance in the endpoint with instance_url returned from authentication token web callout.

```
        Http h1 = new Http();   
        HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
        **req1.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+ objAuthenticationInfo.access_token);**
        req1.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        req1.setHeader('Accept','application/json');
        req1.setMethod('GET');
        req1.setEndpoint(objAuthenticationInfo.instance_url+'/services/data/v47.0/query/?q=SELECT+name+from+account');
        HttpResponse res1 = h1.send(req1);
```

Comment: This does not apply here. The user is not executing their own OAuth flow, and this code seems to be pasted from a very different context.